# How to prevent Saxon/C Python bindings from trying to start a new java VM when another is active? (JNI_CreateJavaVM() failed with result: -5)

Tags: python, saxon, saxon-c

I am building a flask api that allows users to pass an xml and a transformation that returns the xml on which the transformation is performed using Saxon/C's python API (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html).

The incoming endpoint looks like this (removed logging and irrelevant info):

```
@app.route("/v1/transform/", methods=["POST"])
def transform():
    xml = request.data
    transformation = request.args.get("transformation")

    result = transform_xml(xml, transformation)

    return result
```

The transform function looks like this:

```
    def transform_xml(xml: bytes, transformation: str) -> str:
        with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
            base_dir = os.getcwd()
            xslt_path = os.path.join(base_dir, "resources", transformation, "main.xslt")

            xslt_proc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()

            node = proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml.decode("utf-8"))

            result = xslt_proc.transform_to_string(stylesheet_file=xslt_path, xdm_node=node)
            
            return result
```

The xslt's are locally available and a user should choose one of the available ones by passing the corresponding `transformation` name.

Now the problem is, this works (fast) for the first incoming call, but the second one crashes:

```
JNI_CreateJavaVM() failed with result: -5
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 517095) died :( trying respawn ...
```

What does work is changing the transform_xml function like this:

```
        proc = saxonc.PySaxonProcessor(license=False)

        xslt_path = self.__get_path_to_xslt(transformation)

        xslt_proc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()

        node = proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml.decode("utf-8"))

        result = xslt_proc.transform_to_string(stylesheet_file=xslt_path, xdm_node=node)
        
        return result
```

But this leads to the resources never getting released and over time (1k+ requests) this starts to fill up the memory.

It seems like Saxon is trying to create a new VM while the old one is going down.

I found this thread from 2016: https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/4/topics/6399 but this didn't clear it up for me. I looked at the github for the pysaxon repo, but I have found no answer to this problem.
Also made a ticket at Saxon: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4942

Comment: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4428 might be relevant but I have idea whether it resolves your issue.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the threading is an issue. I have configured my flask api with 1 worker and 1 process. Thanks for the link anyway :)

Comment: When the @PySaxonProcessor@ class is used as the context the release method is called, which will clear up Jet VM runtime. I see your last examples will work since the `PySaxonProcessor` object is not created as a context. Your first example should work given you have only 1 worker and 1 process. I will investigate this further. What is your environment? Is this program behind a web server?

Comment: The same problem happens when manually calling the release function before returning the result in the second example by the way.
I am using python 3.8.6 on Ubuntu 20.10. The flask app is run using uWSGI with the following config: 
```[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 1
workers = 1

http = 0.0.0.0:8080 
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Comment: I have made a very small application showcasing the problem with as little code as possible. https://github.com/RudolfDG/saxon-flask-api

Comment: Still investigating this issue. Responded here https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4942

Comment: This bug issue has now been resolved and will be in the next maintenance release. Also see: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5373